# value - is not a member of type parameter T | Scala Error

Tags: scala, generics

I am using Scala 2.13.
I wrote the following code representing a 2D Point which works on only scala.math.Numeric types:

```
class Point[T: Numeric](val x: T, val y: T) {

  def getDistance(otherPoint: Point[T]): Double = {
    math.sqrt(math.pow(otherPoint.x - x, 2) + math.pow(otherPoint.y - y, 2))
  }

  override def toString = "(" + x + "," + y + ")"

}
```

in the 4th line, I get the error "value - is not a member of type parameter T", click to see the location where error occurs:
[click to see error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL875.png)

Where am I going wrong here? (I am new to generics, type bounds in scala)

Comment: Please format properly your code.

Comment: @cchantep, I have formatted the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an extra `import` to enable the convenient symbol ops on a `Numeric`.

After that, feed `pow()` a parameter type that it understands.

```
class Point[T: Numeric](val x: T, val y: T) {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  def getDistance(otherPoint: Point[T]): Double = {
    math.sqrt(math.pow((otherPoint.x - x).toDouble, 2) +
      math.pow((otherPoint.y - y).toDouble, 2))
  }
  override def toString = "(" + x + "," + y + ")"
}
```

Comment: If you use `toDouble` this way (instead of e.g. `(otherPoint.x - x).toDouble`), you don't have operators on `T` anymore and don't need the import.

Comment: Actually that's not completely correct. We can't do `.toDouble` on a raw `Numeric` without the import. Of course we could do `ev.toDouble(x)` if we had `ev`. (Darn that context bound! ;o)

Comment: "Of course we could do ev.toDouble(x) if we had ev" `Numeric.apply` can be used here (though I do prefer to name the parameter instead).

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1:

To use mathematical operators given a `Numeric` bound, you need to

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
```

(and `Fractional/Integral.Implicits._` to get division operations). Without it you need to do something like

```
Numeric[T].minus(otherPoint.x, x)
```

or to give a name to the implicit `Numeric` parameter instead of using a context bound. With the import you can just write

```
otherPoint.x - x
```

The import can be declared at any scope: usually at the top of the file, but it can go inside the method if you only need it once.

Problem 2:

`math.pow` works only on `Double`, and there's no equivalent function for all `Numeric`s in the standard library. So convert to `Double` using `toDouble` method (you could define a generic squaring function, but not really square root).